# self contained deployment using .net core 2.2 is taking much time to respond

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-core-2.2, self-contained

am currently using .netcore 2.2 version with self contained mode of deployment using azure pipeline, but without self contained mode response from the application is within a second but self contained mode takes more than 5 seconds to respond.

self contained along with PublishTrimmed

Comment: Can you share more details about the error scenario? How you define the Azure Pipeline for deployment?  Where did you see the 5s delay？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.